# "Au titre de la Promotion XXXX"

Tags: sens, éducation

I was reading a diploma and saw: "Au titre de la Promotion XXXX". What does that expression mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'expression n'est pas très claire. Elle est assez passe-partout.

On aurait pu dire : *pour l'année 2011*

**Le terme promotion est là pour clarifier les choses, et fixer une liste officielle par année**, pour éviter la confusion due aux dates de recrutement, des examens, d'obtention des diplômes et pour tenir compte des différentes filières d'arrivée et de cursus.

**Pour être plus clairs, les examens et diplômes de l’Éducation Nationale et de l'enseignement supérieur mentionnent en général, et plus simplement:**

> au titre de (pour, à) la **session** (mois) 2011 = lors des examens de 2011.

Selon les écoles et les modes de recrutement:

**Promotion 2011 peut vouloir dire :**

- Cas 1: année de sélection, de recrutement.
- Cas 2: année de sortie et d'obtention réelle du diplôme.

Cas 1: Les corps de la fonction publique ont un concours de recrutement: police, magistrature, ...

Cas 2: Les écoles d'ingénieur et de commerce ont en général un concours de recrutement, et un examen de sortie qui aboutit au diplôme, comme HEC.

L'école Polytechnique, ancienne (fonction publique et école militaire), elle, se fonde sur l'année d'entrée à l'école, et relève du cas 1, bien qu'elle ait aussi un concours (classement) de sortie.

**à l'école spéciale militaire de Saint-Cyr, on utilise les 2 années, ce qui évite de se poser la question :**

http://www.saint-cyr.org/fr/liste-des-promotions,53.html

À l'armée, au temps du service militaire obligatoire, on parlait de ***classe*** année/mois (mois pairs).

**Le terme promotion est également utilisé pour [l'attribution de la légion d'honneur](http://www.legiondhonneur.fr/fr/page/promotions/106).**

[voir l'origine du terme ici, qui avait le sens de montée en grade, ou d'entrée dans une école militaire.](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/promotion)

Comment: Les écoles des Mines constituent une autre exception au cas des écoles d'ingénieur utilisant l'année de sortie comme promotion, mais je n'ai jamais réussi à en trouver la raison.

Answer (score 1):

"by the motive of" (e.g. for an award). 
Here the "motive" is the precision "in the context of the promotion 2011 you were part of". (promotion, for ranking, is the generation. for school degree, the number is the year of the final diploma).

Answer (score 1):

"Au titre de" la promotion 2011 = "deserved as a part of" the 2011 graduation year -- although, as mentioned by others, 2011 is ambiguous and could mean the first or the last year of schooling at HEC.